# Not able to accept the alert in selenium java - Firefox browser

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rSmgW.png)I will open a window to perform some actions and open a new tab in same window. Once new tab is opened, I switch to previous window to continue the execution and once its done, i will switch to the second window to perform actions. When the URL is opened in 2nd window, it is not accepting the alert and throws an exception.

> org.openqa.selenium.UnhandledAlertException: :

This works fine when I open a new Firefox driver in a new window.

```
    try
    {
        Alert alert=DRIVER.switchTo().alert();
        alert.accept();
    }
    catch(NoAlertPresentException e)
    {
        System.out.println("No alert");
    }
```

I tried with the below code as well -

```
    WebDriverWait wait= new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
    Alert alert = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());
    alert.accept();
```

Code to switch to window -

```
    String windowHandle = DRIVER.getWindowHandle();                  
    DRIVER.findElement(By.cssSelector("body")).sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL +"t");
    ArrayList<String> tabs = new ArrayList<String>(DRIVER.getWindowHandles());
    DRIVER.switchTo().window(tabs.get(1)); 
    DRIVER.switchTo().window((String) DRIVER.getWindowHandles().toArray()[0]);
    DRIVER.switchTo().window((String) DRIVER.getWindowHandles().toArray()[1]);
```

Could someone please tell what the issue is? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm new to Java Selenium. Any suggestion would be of great help!

Comment: If the alert belongs to OS (file download dialog, proxy auth., etc.) selenium will never reach it (even see). In such cases you need to avoid the alert.

Comment: Update the question with the code trials for _...switch to the second window ... accepting the alert..._

Comment: When I open this URL in a new window, it is able to handle the alert.

Comment: Isn't there any way we can do this ?

Answer (score 0):

with `Thread.sleep(500);` before `DRIVER.switchTo().window(tabs.get(1));` should work

Comment: I reviewed my code to switch between tabs. I have one more Thread.sleep(100); after opening new tab.

Comment: can you provide the URL so I can try it by myself?